# testing twig with phpunit

Tags: unit-testing, phpunit, twig, slim

I want to implement some unit tests with Twig and PHPUnit(both installed with composer, with slim/views added). But when I try to test a template generation, it blocks at {{ baseUrl() }}. But the templates works fine when I test it on the navigator, without phpunit.

here is the error message :

```
Twig_Error_Runtime: An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template 
("Undefined index: REQUEST_METHOD") in "application/General.twig" at line 21.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described in [this article](http://blog.shaharia.com/write-unit-test-for-slim-framework/), It’s not so easy to write Test Cases for slim framework. You could mock the SLIM Environment as follow:

```
// Prepare a mock environment
        Environment::mock(array_merge(array(
            'REQUEST_METHOD' => $method,
            'PATH_INFO' => $path,
            'SERVER_NAME' => 'slim-test.dev',
        ), $options));
        $app = new \Slim\Slim();
        $this->app = $app;
        $this->request = $app->request();
        $this->response = $app->response();
```

Full code example in [this gist](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/shahariaazam/8523437/raw/95cf2ea2c66e1512120a60cccc0ab3fbb8139faf/Slim_RoutesTest.php)

Hope this help

Comment: works fin ! thanks a lot ! I suspected the error to be related to Twig instead of slim ^^